# How to create PQ sorted according to the natural ordering of a list?

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

My SSCE:

```
public class ComparableItem implements Comparable<ComparableItem> {

    private final int itemNo;

    public ComparableItem(final int itemNo) {
        this.itemNo = itemNo;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableItem o) {
        if (this.itemNo < o.itemNo) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.itemNo > o.itemNo) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here's a test that demonstrates the problem. The code breaks after the PQ is created. The lines above are to prove that the natural ordering defined by compareTo(..) works as expected.
Printing the elements of the PQ they are: 14,9,15,5,6,3 versus the expected 15,14,9,6,5,3. Could someone explain to me why this is the case?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class CompTest{

@Test
public void aTest() {

    Integer[] order = {9, 3, 14, 15, 6, 5};
    List<ComparableItem> items = new ArrayList<ComparableItem>(order.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        items.add(new ComparableItem(order[i]));
    }

    List<ComparableItem> greater = new ArrayList<ComparableItem>();
    testCompare(items, items.get(3), greater, true);
    testCompare(items, items.get(2), greater, true);
    testCompare(items, items.get(0), greater, true);
    testCompare(items, items.get(4), greater, true);
    testCompare(items, items.get(5), greater, true);
    testCompare(items, items.get(1), greater, true);

    final PriorityQueue<ComparableItem> itemsQueue = new PriorityQueue<ComparableItem>(items);
    greater = new ArrayList<ComparableItem>();
    for (ComparableItem c : itemsQueue) {
        testCompare(itemsQueue, c, greater, false);
    }
}

public static void testCompare(final Collection<ComparableItem> items, final ComparableItem item, final List<ComparableItem> greater, boolean bigger) {
    final int exp = (bigger)? -1:1;
    for (ComparableItem c : items) {
        final int expected = c.equals(item) ? 0 : greater.contains(c) ? exp : exp*-1;
        assertEquals(expected, item.compareTo(c));
        assertEquals(expected * -1, c.compareTo(item));
    }
    greater.add(item);
}
```

}

```
new PriorityQueue<ComparableItem>(items);
```

> Creates a PriorityQueue containing the
>   elements in the specified collection.
>   If the specified collection is an
>   instance of a SortedSet or is another
>   PriorityQueue, this priority queue
>   will be ordered according to the same
>   ordering. Otherwise, this priority
>   queue will be ordered according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is not in the queue, but in the way that you are testing it.  In particular, the javadoc for [`PriorityQueue.iterator()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator%28%29) states:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

And the class javadoc says this:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

Comment: you are right. This makes the test run:
while (!itemsQueue.isEmpty()) {
        ComparableItem c = itemsQueue.poll();
        testCompare(itemsQueue, c, greater, false);
    }